# Kafka Streams: one record to multiple records

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

Given: I have two topics in Kafka let's say topic A and topic B. The Kafka Stream reads a record from topic A, processes it and produces multiple records (let's say recordA and recordB) corresponding to the consumed record. Now, the question is how can I achieve this using Kafka Streams.

```java
KStream<String, List<Message>> producerStreams[] = recordStream.mapValues(new ValueMapper<Message, List<Message>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Message> apply(final Message message) {
          return consumerRecordHandler.process(message);
        }
    }).*someFunction*()
```

Here, the record read is Message; After processing it returns a list of Message. How can I divide this list to two producer streams? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, and I also don't understand the answer from @Abhishek :(

If you have an input stream, and you want to get zero, one, or more output records per input records, you would apply a `flatMap()` or `flatMapValues()` (depending if you want to modify the key or not).

You are also asking about "How can I divide this list to two producer streams?" If you mean to split one stream into multiple, you can use `branch()`.

For more details, I refer to the docs:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#stateless-transformations

Comment: @user2538255 Feel free to follow up if my answer is unclear.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am doing. After some googling on Abhishek's answer, I landed on this example https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/kafka-0.10.0.0-cp-3.0.0/kafka-streams/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaIntegrationTest.java

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax is there a way to achieve some kind of transactional flat mapping? If one records processes N as a result of a flat map, I want all N or 0 in the outbound topic.

Comment: If you enable exactly once processing, you get what you ask :)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - Is the example of WordCountLambdaIntegrationTest.java mentioned by @ user2538255 available in the latest version of confluent examples?

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/6.1.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaIntegrationTest.java

Answer (score 3):

What's your key (type) ? I am guessing its not `String`. After executing the `mapValues` you'll have this - `KStream<K,List<Message>>`. If `K` is not `String` then `someFunction()` can be a `map` which will convert `K` into `String` (if its is, you already have the result) and leave the `List<Message>` (the value) untouched since that's your intended end result